# Defining Singleton in AOSP, Android

Tags: java, android, singleton, android-source

I am working on a custom AOSP rom. So, I have modified some system classes and created new classes. My problem is defining a **Singleton class**. With this pattern, we can create one object for each request, can't we? But somehow, when i build aosp, i see more than one same class, generated for each Android application.

```
public final Singleton{
 private static Singleton singleton;
 private int peakValue = -1;

 private Singleton(){}

 public static Singleton getInstance(){
  if(singleton == null)
    singleton = new Singleton();
  return singleton;
 }

 public int getPeakValue(){
    return getInstance().peakValue;
 }

 public void setPeakValue(int val){
   getInstance().peakValue = val; 
 }

}
```

At logcat,

```
........ApplicationName1 : .......Singleton@1000abafe1
........ApplicationName2 : .......Singleton@1000abafee
```

So, When i call `Singleton.getInstance().getPeakValue();` it returns `null`, even though i have already set value.

Can anyone help me?
How can i define Singletons?

Answer (score 2):

Create a service that contains the singleton and bind to it. Then there will only be one instance of your service at a time.

Each application has its own JVM which is why your approach isn't working.

Comment: can you share or give an example?

Comment: http://opensourceforu.efytimes.com/2013/12/birds-eye-view-android-system-services/

Comment: if i define a service and bound int value to it where singleton is setted, Then can i get this value via getInstance in any class or application?

Comment: @reigeki You will have to expose a service via system_server to share the value. Even if you were to have a Singleton, each app has its own process and its own virtual machine so that Singleton only applies to that running process. Look into how a service like LocationManagerService works and then look at SystemServer.java to add the service. Your applications will have to then call the service to obtain the shared values.